# Perl Support Mac Error

Tags: mysql, macos, perl

**I am trying to install perl support for my mac but every time i do so I get the same error**

I typed in command line cpan -f -i DBI and recieved the same error over and over again.

```
admins-iMac-2:~ robensonsam$ cpan -f -i DBI
Reading '/Users/robinsensam/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Wed, 04 Jan 2017 11:29:02 GMT
Running install for module 'DBI'
Running make for T/TI/TIMB/DBI-1.636.tar.gz
Checksum for /Users/robinsensam/.cpan/sources/authors/id/T/TI/TIMB/DBI-1.636.tar.gz ok

  CPAN.pm: Building T/TI/TIMB/DBI-1.636.tar.gz


*** Your LANG environment variable is set to 'en_US.UTF-8'
*** This may cause problems for some perl installations.
*** If you get test failures, please try again with LANG unset.
*** If that then works, please email dbi-dev@perl.org with details
*** including the output of 'perl -V'

Your perl was compiled with gcc (version 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.34)), okay.
Creating test wrappers for DBD::Gofer:
t/zvg_01basics.t 
t/zvg_02dbidrv.t 
t/zvg_03handle.t 
t/zvg_04mods.t 
t/zvg_05concathash.t 
t/zvg_06attrs.t 
t/zvg_07kids.t 
t/zvg_08keeperr.t 
t/zvg_09trace.t 
t/zvg_10examp.t 
t/zvg_11fetch.t 
t/zvg_12quote.t 
t/zvg_13taint.t 
t/zvg_14utf8.t 
t/zvg_15array.t 
t/zvg_16destroy.t 
t/zvg_19fhtrace.t 
t/zvg_20meta.t 
t/zvg_30subclass.t 
t/zvg_31methcache.t 
t/zvg_35thrclone.t (use threads)
t/zvg_40profile.t 
t/zvg_41prof_dump.t 
t/zvg_42prof_data.t 
t/zvg_43prof_env.t 
t/zvg_48dbi_dbd_sqlengine.t 
t/zvg_49dbd_file.t 
t/zvg_50dbm_simple.t 
t/zvg_51dbm_file.t 
t/zvg_52dbm_complex.t 
t/zvg_53sqlengine_adv.t 
t/zvg_60preparse.t 
t/zvg_65transact.t 
t/zvg_70callbacks.t 
t/zvg_72childhandles.t 
t/zvg_73cachedkids.t 
t/zvg_80proxy.t 
t/zvg_85gofer.t 
t/zvg_86gofer_fail.t 
t/zvg_87gofer_cache.t 
t/zvg_90sql_type_cast.t 
t/zvg_91_store_warning.t 
Creating test wrappers for DBI::SQL::Nano:
t/zvn_48dbi_dbd_sqlengine.t 
t/zvn_49dbd_file.t 
t/zvn_50dbm_simple.t 
t/zvn_51dbm_file.t 
t/zvn_52dbm_complex.t 
t/zvn_85gofer.t 
Creating test wrappers for DBI::PurePerl:
t/zvp_01basics.t 
t/zvp_02dbidrv.t 
t/zvp_03handle.t 
t/zvp_04mods.t 
t/zvp_05concathash.t 
t/zvp_06attrs.t 
t/zvp_07kids.t 
t/zvp_08keeperr.t 
t/zvp_09trace.t 
t/zvp_10examp.t 
t/zvp_11fetch.t 
t/zvp_12quote.t 
t/zvp_13taint.t 
t/zvp_14utf8.t 
t/zvp_15array.t 
t/zvp_16destroy.t 
t/zvp_19fhtrace.t 
t/zvp_20meta.t 
t/zvp_30subclass.t 
t/zvp_31methcache.t 
t/zvp_35thrclone.t (use threads)
t/zvp_40profile.t 
t/zvp_41prof_dump.t 
t/zvp_42prof_data.t 
t/zvp_43prof_env.t 
t/zvp_48dbi_dbd_sqlengine.t 
t/zvp_49dbd_file.t 
t/zvp_50dbm_simple.t 
t/zvp_51dbm_file.t 
t/zvp_52dbm_complex.t 
t/zvp_53sqlengine_adv.t 
t/zvp_60preparse.t 
t/zvp_65transact.t 
t/zvp_70callbacks.t 
t/zvp_72childhandles.t 
t/zvp_73cachedkids.t 
t/zvp_80proxy.t 
t/zvp_85gofer.t 
t/zvp_86gofer_fail.t 
t/zvp_87gofer_cache.t 
t/zvp_90sql_type_cast.t 
t/zvp_91_store_warning.t 
Creating test wrappers for DBD::Gofer + DBI::SQL::Nano:
t/zvxgn_48dbi_dbd_sqlengine.t 
t/zvxgn_49dbd_file.t 
t/zvxgn_50dbm_simple.t 
t/zvxgn_51dbm_file.t 
t/zvxgn_52dbm_complex.t 
t/zvxgn_85gofer.t 
Creating test wrappers for DBD::Gofer + DBI::PurePerl:
t/zvxgp_01basics.t 
t/zvxgp_02dbidrv.t 
t/zvxgp_03handle.t 
t/zvxgp_04mods.t 
t/zvxgp_05concathash.t 
t/zvxgp_06attrs.t 
t/zvxgp_07kids.t 
t/zvxgp_08keeperr.t 
t/zvxgp_09trace.t 
t/zvxgp_10examp.t 
t/zvxgp_11fetch.t 
t/zvxgp_12quote.t 
t/zvxgp_13taint.t 
t/zvxgp_14utf8.t 
t/zvxgp_15array.t 
t/zvxgp_16destroy.t 
t/zvxgp_19fhtrace.t 
t/zvxgp_20meta.t 
t/zvxgp_30subclass.t 
t/zvxgp_31methcache.t 
t/zvxgp_35thrclone.t (use threads)
t/zvxgp_40profile.t 
t/zvxgp_41prof_dump.t 
t/zvxgp_42prof_data.t 
t/zvxgp_43prof_env.t 
t/zvxgp_48dbi_dbd_sqlengine.t 
t/zvxgp_49dbd_file.t 
t/zvxgp_50dbm_simple.t 
t/zvxgp_51dbm_file.t 
t/zvxgp_52dbm_complex.t 
t/zvxgp_53sqlengine_adv.t 
t/zvxgp_60preparse.t 
t/zvxgp_65transact.t 
t/zvxgp_70callbacks.t 
t/zvxgp_72childhandles.t 
t/zvxgp_73cachedkids.t 
t/zvxgp_80proxy.t 
t/zvxgp_85gofer.t 
t/zvxgp_86gofer_fail.t 
t/zvxgp_87gofer_cache.t 
t/zvxgp_90sql_type_cast.t 
t/zvxgp_91_store_warning.t 
Creating test wrappers for DBI::SQL::Nano + DBI::PurePerl:
t/zvxnp_48dbi_dbd_sqlengine.t 
t/zvxnp_49dbd_file.t 
t/zvxnp_50dbm_simple.t 
t/zvxnp_51dbm_file.t 
t/zvxnp_52dbm_complex.t 
t/zvxnp_85gofer.t 
Creating test wrappers for DBD::Gofer + DBI::SQL::Nano + DBI::PurePerl:
t/zvxgnp_48dbi_dbd_sqlengine.t 
t/zvxgnp_49dbd_file.t 
t/zvxgnp_50dbm_simple.t 
t/zvxgnp_51dbm_file.t 
t/zvxgnp_52dbm_complex.t 
t/zvxgnp_85gofer.t 
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good

    I see you're using perl 5.018002 on darwin-thread-multi-2level, okay.
    Remember to actually *read* the README file!
    Use  'make' to build the software (dmake or nmake on Windows).
    Then 'make test' to execute self tests.
    Then 'make install' to install the DBI and then delete this working
    directory before unpacking and building any DBD::* drivers.

Writing Makefile for DBI
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
/usr/bin/perl -MExtUtils::Command -e 'mkpath' -- blib/lib/DBI
rm -f blib/lib/DBI/Changes.pm
cp Changes blib/lib/DBI/Changes.pm
cp DBIXS.h blib/arch/auto/DBI/DBIXS.h
cp lib/DBD/NullP.pm blib/lib/DBD/NullP.pm
cp lib/DBD/Gofer/Transport/pipeone.pm blib/lib/DBD/Gofer/Transport/pipeone.pm
cp lib/DBD/File.pm blib/lib/DBD/File.pm
cp lib/DBI/ProfileDumper/Apache.pm blib/lib/DBI/ProfileDumper/Apache.pm
cp Driver.xst blib/arch/auto/DBI/Driver.xst
cp lib/DBI/Gofer/Serializer/DataDumper.pm blib/lib/DBI/Gofer/Serializer/DataDumper.pm
cp lib/DBI/Gofer/Serializer/Base.pm blib/lib/DBI/Gofer/Serializer/Base.pm
cp lib/DBD/Gofer/Policy/rush.pm blib/lib/DBD/Gofer/Policy/rush.pm
cp lib/DBD/Proxy.pm blib/lib/DBD/Proxy.pm
cp lib/DBI/Gofer/Serializer/Storable.pm blib/lib/DBI/Gofer/Serializer/Storable.pm
cp lib/DBI/SQL/Nano.pm blib/lib/DBI/SQL/Nano.pm
cp dbd_xsh.h blib/arch/auto/DBI/dbd_xsh.h
cp lib/DBD/File/Developers.pod blib/lib/DBD/File/Developers.pod
cp dbixs_rev.h blib/arch/auto/DBI/dbixs_rev.h
cp lib/DBI/Gofer/Transport/Base.pm blib/lib/DBI/Gofer/Transport/Base.pm
cp lib/DBD/Gofer/Transport/stream.pm blib/lib/DBD/Gofer/Transport/stream.pm
cp lib/DBD/Gofer.pm blib/lib/DBD/Gofer.pm
cp lib/DBI/Util/_accessor.pm blib/lib/DBI/Util/_accessor.pm
cp lib/DBI/Gofer/Transport/pipeone.pm blib/lib/DBI/Gofer/Transport/pipeone.pm
cp lib/DBI/Gofer/Execute.pm blib/lib/DBI/Gofer/Execute.pm
cp lib/DBI/DBD/Metadata.pm blib/lib/DBI/DBD/Metadata.pm
cp lib/DBI/Const/GetInfoType.pm blib/lib/DBI/Const/GetInfoType.pm
cp lib/DBI/Util/CacheMemory.pm blib/lib/DBI/Util/CacheMemory.pm
cp lib/DBI/Profile.pm blib/lib/DBI/Profile.pm
cp lib/DBI/Const/GetInfo/ANSI.pm blib/lib/DBI/Const/GetInfo/ANSI.pm
cp lib/Bundle/DBI.pm blib/lib/Bundle/DBI.pm
cp lib/DBI/W32ODBC.pm blib/lib/DBI/W32ODBC.pm
cp lib/DBI/ProfileData.pm blib/lib/DBI/ProfileData.pm
cp DBI.pm blib/lib/DBI.pm
cp dbipport.h blib/arch/auto/DBI/dbipport.h
cp lib/DBD/Gofer/Policy/Base.pm blib/lib/DBD/Gofer/Policy/Base.pm
cp lib/DBD/File/HowTo.pod blib/lib/DBD/File/HowTo.pod
cp lib/DBI/DBD/SqlEngine/HowTo.pod blib/lib/DBI/DBD/SqlEngine/HowTo.pod
cp lib/DBI/DBD/SqlEngine/Developers.pod blib/lib/DBI/DBD/SqlEngine/Developers.pod
cp lib/DBD/Sponge.pm blib/lib/DBD/Sponge.pm
cp lib/DBD/ExampleP.pm blib/lib/DBD/ExampleP.pm
cp Driver_xst.h blib/arch/auto/DBI/Driver_xst.h
cp lib/DBI/ProfileSubs.pm blib/lib/DBI/ProfileSubs.pm
cp lib/DBI/ProfileDumper.pm blib/lib/DBI/ProfileDumper.pm
cp lib/DBD/Gofer/Transport/corostream.pm blib/lib/DBD/Gofer/Transport/corostream.pm
cp lib/DBI/Gofer/Request.pm blib/lib/DBI/Gofer/Request.pm
cp lib/DBD/Gofer/Policy/pedantic.pm blib/lib/DBD/Gofer/Policy/pedantic.pm
cp lib/DBD/Gofer/Policy/classic.pm blib/lib/DBD/Gofer/Policy/classic.pm
cp lib/DBI/DBD/SqlEngine.pm blib/lib/DBI/DBD/SqlEngine.pm
cp lib/DBI/PurePerl.pm blib/lib/DBI/PurePerl.pm
cp dbixs_rev.pl blib/lib/dbixs_rev.pl
cp lib/DBD/File/Roadmap.pod blib/lib/DBD/File/Roadmap.pod
cp lib/DBI/Const/GetInfo/ODBC.pm blib/lib/DBI/Const/GetInfo/ODBC.pm
cp dbivport.h blib/arch/auto/DBI/dbivport.h
cp lib/DBI/Gofer/Response.pm blib/lib/DBI/Gofer/Response.pm
cp dbi_sql.h blib/arch/auto/DBI/dbi_sql.h
cp lib/DBI/Const/GetInfoReturn.pm blib/lib/DBI/Const/GetInfoReturn.pm
cp lib/DBD/DBM.pm blib/lib/DBD/DBM.pm
cp lib/DBI/Gofer/Transport/stream.pm blib/lib/DBI/Gofer/Transport/stream.pm
cp lib/DBD/Gofer/Transport/null.pm blib/lib/DBD/Gofer/Transport/null.pm
cp lib/Win32/DBIODBC.pm blib/lib/Win32/DBIODBC.pm
cp lib/DBD/Gofer/Transport/Base.pm blib/lib/DBD/Gofer/Transport/Base.pm
cp lib/DBI/DBD.pm blib/lib/DBI/DBD.pm
cp lib/DBI/ProxyServer.pm blib/lib/DBI/ProxyServer.pm
/usr/bin/perl -p -e "s/~DRIVER~/Perl/g" ./Driver.xst > Perl.xsi
/usr/bin/perl /System/Library/Perl/5.18/ExtUtils/xsubpp  -typemap /System/Library/Perl/5.18/ExtUtils/typemap -typemap typemap  Perl.xs > Perl.xsc && mv Perl.xsc Perl.c
cc -c   -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -g -pipe -fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -fno-strict-aliasing -fstack-protector -Os   -DVERSION=\"1.636\" -DXS_VERSION=\"1.636\"  "-I/System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE"  -W -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wbad-function-cast -Wno-comment -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-cast-qual -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-unused-parameter Perl.c
/usr/bin/perl /System/Library/Perl/5.18/ExtUtils/xsubpp  -typemap /System/Library/Perl/5.18/ExtUtils/typemap -typemap typemap  DBI.xs > DBI.xsc && mv DBI.xsc DBI.c
cc -c   -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -g -pipe -fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -fno-strict-aliasing -fstack-protector -Os   -DVERSION=\"1.636\" -DXS_VERSION=\"1.636\"  "-I/System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE"  -W -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wbad-function-cast -Wno-comment -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-cast-qual -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-unused-parameter DBI.c
Running Mkbootstrap for DBI ()
chmod 644 DBI.bs
rm -f blib/arch/auto/DBI/DBI.bundle
cc -mmacosx-version-min=10.12.2  -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -fstack-protector DBI.o  -o blib/arch/auto/DBI/DBI.bundle    \
            \

chmod 755 blib/arch/auto/DBI/DBI.bundle
cp DBI.bs blib/arch/auto/DBI/DBI.bs
chmod 644 blib/arch/auto/DBI/DBI.bs
/usr/bin/perl "-Iblib/arch" "-Iblib/lib" dbiprof.PL dbiprof
Extracted dbiprof from dbiprof.PL with variable substitutions.
cp dbiprof blib/script/dbiprof
/usr/bin/perl -MExtUtils::MY -e 'MY->fixin(shift)' -- blib/script/dbiprof
/usr/bin/perl "-Iblib/arch" "-Iblib/lib" dbiproxy.PL dbiproxy
Extracted dbiproxy from dbiproxy.PL with variable substitutions.
cp dbiproxy blib/script/dbiproxy
/usr/bin/perl -MExtUtils::MY -e 'MY->fixin(shift)' -- blib/script/dbiproxy
/usr/bin/perl "-Iblib/arch" "-Iblib/lib" dbilogstrip.PL dbilogstrip
Extracted dbilogstrip from dbilogstrip.PL with variable substitutions.
cp dbilogstrip blib/script/dbilogstrip
/usr/bin/perl -MExtUtils::MY -e 'MY->fixin(shift)' -- blib/script/dbilogstrip
Manifying blib/man1/dbiproxy.1
Manifying blib/man1/dbilogstrip.1
Manifying blib/man1/dbiprof.1
Manifying blib/man3/DBD::Gofer::Transport::null.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/DBI::DBD::SqlEngine::HowTo.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/DBI::ProfileDumper::Apache.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/DBD::Gofer::Policy::rush.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/DBI::DBD::SqlEngine::Developers.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/DBI::Gofer::Transport::Base.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/DBD::DBM.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/DBD::File::HowTo.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/DBI::Const::GetInfo::ANSI.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/DBI::ProfileDumper.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/DBI::Profile.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/DBI::ProxyServer.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/DBD::Proxy.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/DBD::File::Roadmap.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/DBI::Gofer::Execute.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/DBD::Gofer::Policy::pedantic.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/DBI::Const::GetInfoReturn.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/Bundle::DBI.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/DBI::Util::CacheMemory.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/DBI::ProfileSubs.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/DBI::SQL::Nano.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/DBD::Sponge.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/DBD::Gofer::Policy::classic.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/DBI::Gofer::Request.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/DBI::DBD.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/DBI::Const::GetInfo::ODBC.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/DBD::Gofer::Transport::Base.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/DBD::Gofer::Transport::pipeone.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/DBI::Gofer::Serializer::Base.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/DBI::Const::GetInfoType.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/DBD::Gofer::Transport::corostream.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/DBD::File.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/DBD::Gofer::Policy::Base.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/DBI::Gofer::Serializer::Storable.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/DBI::Gofer::Serializer::DataDumper.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/DBI::Gofer::Response.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/DBI::Gofer::Transport::pipeone.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/Win32::DBIODBC.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/DBD::File::Developers.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/DBI.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/DBI::Gofer::Transport::stream.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/DBI::PurePerl.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/DBI::DBD::SqlEngine.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/DBI::ProfileData.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/DBI::DBD::Metadata.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/DBD::Gofer.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/DBD::Gofer::Transport::stream.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/DBI::W32ODBC.3pm
  TIMB/DBI-1.636.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make -- OK
'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
Running make test
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 /usr/bin/perl "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-e" "test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/01basics.t .................... # --- Perl 5.018002 on darwin-thread-multi-2level
t/01basics.t .................... ok       
t/02dbidrv.t .................... ok     
t/03handle.t .................... ok       
t/04mods.t ...................... ok     
t/05concathash.t ................ ok     
t/06attrs.t ..................... ok     
t/07kids.t ...................... ok     
t/08keeperr.t ................... ok    
t/09trace.t ..................... ok     
t/10examp.t ..................... ok       
t/11fetch.t ..................... ok     
t/12quote.t ..................... ok     
t/13taint.t ..................... ok     
t/14utf8.t ...................... ok     
t/15array.t ..................... ok     
t/16destroy.t ................... ok     
t/19fhtrace.t ................... ok     
t/20meta.t ...................... ok   
t/30subclass.t .................. ok     
t/31methcache.t ................. ok     
t/35thrclone.t .................. ok     
t/40profile.t ................... ok     
t/41prof_dump.t ................. ok     
t/42prof_data.t ................. ok     
t/43prof_env.t .................. ok     
t/48dbi_dbd_sqlengine.t ......... ok    
t/49dbd_file.t .................. ok    
t/50dbm_simple.t ................ ok     
t/51dbm_file.t .................. ok    
t/52dbm_complex.t ............... skipped: DBI::SQL::Nano is being used
t/53sqlengine_adv.t ............. ok   
t/60preparse.t .................. ok     
t/65transact.t .................. ok     
t/70callbacks.t ................. ok    
t/72childhandles.t .............. ok     
t/73cachedkids.t ................ ok    
t/80proxy.t ..................... skipped: modules required for proxy are probably not installed (e.g., RPC/PlClient.pm)
t/85gofer.t ..................... ok     
t/86gofer_fail.t ................ ok    
t/87gofer_cache.t ............... ok    
t/90sql_type_cast.t ............. ok     
t/91_store_warning.t ............ ok   
t/pod-coverage.t ................ skipped: Test::Pod::Coverage 1.04 required for testing POD coverage
t/pod.t ......................... ok     
t/zvg_01basics.t ................ # --- Perl 5.018002 on darwin-thread-multi-2level
t/zvg_01basics.t ................ ok       
t/zvg_02dbidrv.t ................ ok     
t/zvg_03handle.t ................ ok       
t/zvg_04mods.t .................. ok     
t/zvg_05concathash.t ............ ok     
t/zvg_06attrs.t ................. ok     
t/zvg_07kids.t .................. ok     
t/zvg_08keeperr.t ............... ok    
t/zvg_09trace.t ................. ok     
t/zvg_10examp.t ................. ok       
t/zvg_11fetch.t ................. ok     
t/zvg_12quote.t ................. ok     
t/zvg_13taint.t ................. skipped: Taint attribute tests not functional with DBI_AUTOPROXY
t/zvg_14utf8.t .................. ok     
t/zvg_15array.t ................. ok     
t/zvg_16destroy.t ............... ok     
t/zvg_19fhtrace.t ............... ok     
t/zvg_20meta.t .................. ok   
t/zvg_30subclass.t .............. ok     
t/zvg_31methcache.t ............. ok     
t/zvg_35thrclone.t .............. ok     
t/zvg_40profile.t ............... ok     
t/zvg_41prof_dump.t ............. ok     
t/zvg_42prof_data.t ............. ok     
t/zvg_43prof_env.t .............. ok     
t/zvg_48dbi_dbd_sqlengine.t ..... ok    
t/zvg_49dbd_file.t .............. ok    
t/zvg_50dbm_simple.t ............ ok     
t/zvg_51dbm_file.t .............. ok   
t/zvg_52dbm_complex.t ........... skipped: DBI::SQL::Nano is being used
t/zvg_53sqlengine_adv.t ......... skipped: Modifying driver state won't compute running behind Gofer
t/zvg_60preparse.t .............. ok     
t/zvg_65transact.t .............. skipped: Transactions not supported by DBD::Gofer
t/zvg_70callbacks.t ............. ok    
t/zvg_72childhandles.t .......... ok     
t/zvg_73cachedkids.t ............ ok    
t/zvg_80proxy.t ................. skipped: modules required for proxy are probably not installed (e.g., RPC/PlClient.pm)
t/zvg_85gofer.t ................. ok     
t/zvg_86gofer_fail.t ............ skipped: Gofer DBI_AUTOPROXY
t/zvg_87gofer_cache.t ........... skipped: Gofer DBI_AUTOPROXY
t/zvg_90sql_type_cast.t ......... ok     
t/zvg_91_store_warning.t ........ ok   
t/zvn_48dbi_dbd_sqlengine.t ..... ok    
t/zvn_49dbd_file.t .............. ok    
t/zvn_50dbm_simple.t ............ ok     
t/zvn_51dbm_file.t .............. ok    
t/zvn_52dbm_complex.t ........... skipped: DBI::SQL::Nano is being used
t/zvn_85gofer.t ................. ok     
t/zvp_01basics.t ................ # --- Perl 5.018002 on darwin-thread-multi-2level
t/zvp_01basics.t ................ ok       
t/zvp_02dbidrv.t ................ ok     
t/zvp_03handle.t ................ ok       
t/zvp_04mods.t .................. ok     
t/zvp_05concathash.t ............ ok     
t/zvp_06attrs.t ................. ok     
t/zvp_07kids.t .................. skipped: $h->{Kids} attribute not supported for DBI::PurePerl
t/zvp_08keeperr.t ............... ok    
t/zvp_09trace.t ................. ok     
t/zvp_10examp.t ................. ok       
t/zvp_11fetch.t ................. ok     
t/zvp_12quote.t ................. ok     
t/zvp_13taint.t ................. skipped: Taint attributes not supported with DBI::PurePerl
t/zvp_14utf8.t .................. ok     
t/zvp_15array.t ................. ok     
t/zvp_16destroy.t ............... ok     
t/zvp_19fhtrace.t ............... ok     
t/zvp_20meta.t .................. ok   
t/zvp_30subclass.t .............. ok     
t/zvp_31methcache.t ............. ok     
t/zvp_35thrclone.t .............. ok     
t/zvp_40profile.t ............... skipped: profiling not supported for DBI::PurePerl
t/zvp_41prof_dump.t ............. skipped: profiling not supported for DBI::PurePerl
t/zvp_42prof_data.t ............. skipped: profiling not supported for DBI::PurePerl
t/zvp_43prof_env.t .............. skipped: profiling not supported for DBI::PurePerl
t/zvp_48dbi_dbd_sqlengine.t ..... ok    
t/zvp_49dbd_file.t .............. ok    
t/zvp_50dbm_simple.t ............ ok     
t/zvp_51dbm_file.t .............. ok    
t/zvp_52dbm_complex.t ........... skipped: DBI::SQL::Nano is being used
t/zvp_53sqlengine_adv.t ......... ok   
t/zvp_60preparse.t .............. skipped: preparse not supported for DBI::PurePerl
t/zvp_65transact.t .............. ok     
t/zvp_70callbacks.t ............. skipped: $h->{Callbacks} attribute not supported for DBI::PurePerl
t/zvp_72childhandles.t .......... ok     
t/zvp_73cachedkids.t ............ ok    
t/zvp_80proxy.t ................. skipped: modules required for proxy are probably not installed (e.g., RPC/PlClient.pm)
t/zvp_85gofer.t ................. ok     
t/zvp_86gofer_fail.t ............ skipped: requires Callbacks which are not supported with PurePerl
t/zvp_87gofer_cache.t ........... ok    
t/zvp_90sql_type_cast.t ......... ok     
t/zvp_91_store_warning.t ........ ok   
t/zvxgn_48dbi_dbd_sqlengine.t ... ok    
t/zvxgn_49dbd_file.t ............ ok    
t/zvxgn_50dbm_simple.t .......... ok     
t/zvxgn_51dbm_file.t ............ ok   
t/zvxgn_52dbm_complex.t ......... skipped: DBI::SQL::Nano is being used
t/zvxgn_85gofer.t ............... ok     
t/zvxgnp_48dbi_dbd_sqlengine.t .. ok    
t/zvxgnp_49dbd_file.t ........... ok    
t/zvxgnp_50dbm_simple.t ......... ok     
t/zvxgnp_51dbm_file.t ........... ok   
t/zvxgnp_52dbm_complex.t ........ skipped: DBI::SQL::Nano is being used
t/zvxgnp_85gofer.t .............. ok     
t/zvxgp_01basics.t .............. # --- Perl 5.018002 on darwin-thread-multi-2level
t/zvxgp_01basics.t .............. ok       
t/zvxgp_02dbidrv.t .............. ok     
t/zvxgp_03handle.t .............. ok       
t/zvxgp_04mods.t ................ ok     
t/zvxgp_05concathash.t .......... ok     
t/zvxgp_06attrs.t ............... ok     
t/zvxgp_07kids.t ................ skipped: $h->{Kids} attribute not supported for DBI::PurePerl
t/zvxgp_08keeperr.t ............. ok    
t/zvxgp_09trace.t ............... ok     
t/zvxgp_10examp.t ............... ok       
t/zvxgp_11fetch.t ............... ok     
t/zvxgp_12quote.t ............... ok     
t/zvxgp_13taint.t ............... skipped: Taint attributes not supported with DBI::PurePerl
t/zvxgp_14utf8.t ................ ok     
t/zvxgp_15array.t ............... ok     
t/zvxgp_16destroy.t ............. ok     
t/zvxgp_19fhtrace.t ............. ok     
t/zvxgp_20meta.t ................ ok   
t/zvxgp_30subclass.t ............ ok     
t/zvxgp_31methcache.t ........... ok     
t/zvxgp_35thrclone.t ............ ok     
t/zvxgp_40profile.t ............. skipped: profiling not supported for DBI::PurePerl
t/zvxgp_41prof_dump.t ........... skipped: profiling not supported for DBI::PurePerl
t/zvxgp_42prof_data.t ........... skipped: profiling not supported for DBI::PurePerl
t/zvxgp_43prof_env.t ............ skipped: profiling not supported for DBI::PurePerl
t/zvxgp_48dbi_dbd_sqlengine.t ... ok    
t/zvxgp_49dbd_file.t ............ ok    
t/zvxgp_50dbm_simple.t .......... ok     
t/zvxgp_51dbm_file.t ............ ok   
t/zvxgp_52dbm_complex.t ......... skipped: DBI::SQL::Nano is being used
t/zvxgp_53sqlengine_adv.t ....... skipped: Modifying driver state won't compute running behind Gofer
t/zvxgp_60preparse.t ............ skipped: preparse not supported for DBI::PurePerl
t/zvxgp_65transact.t ............ skipped: Transactions not supported by DBD::Gofer
t/zvxgp_70callbacks.t ........... skipped: $h->{Callbacks} attribute not supported for DBI::PurePerl
t/zvxgp_72childhandles.t ........ ok     
t/zvxgp_73cachedkids.t .......... ok    
t/zvxgp_80proxy.t ............... skipped: modules required for proxy are probably not installed (e.g., RPC/PlClient.pm)
t/zvxgp_85gofer.t ............... ok     
t/zvxgp_86gofer_fail.t .......... skipped: requires Callbacks which are not supported with PurePerl
t/zvxgp_87gofer_cache.t ......... skipped: Gofer DBI_AUTOPROXY
t/zvxgp_90sql_type_cast.t ....... ok     
t/zvxgp_91_store_warning.t ...... ok   
t/zvxnp_48dbi_dbd_sqlengine.t ... ok    
t/zvxnp_49dbd_file.t ............ ok    
t/zvxnp_50dbm_simple.t .......... ok     
t/zvxnp_51dbm_file.t ............ ok    
t/zvxnp_52dbm_complex.t ......... skipped: DBI::SQL::Nano is being used
t/zvxnp_85gofer.t ............... ok     
All tests successful.
Files=194, Tests=10553, 99 wallclock secs ( 1.74 usr  0.56 sys + 80.15 cusr  9.49 csys = 91.94 CPU)
Result: PASS
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 /usr/bin/perl "-Iblib/lib" "-Iblib/arch" test.pl
test.pl 
DBI test application $Revision$
Switch: DBI 1.636 by Tim Bunce, 1.636
Available Drivers: DBM, ExampleP, File, Gofer, Proxy, SQLite, Sponge
dbi:ExampleP:: testing 3 sets of 20 connections:
Connecting... 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 
Disconnecting...
Connecting... 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 
Disconnecting...
Connecting... 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 
Disconnecting...
connect 20 and disconnect them, 3 times: 0.0016s / 60 = 0.0000s
Testing handle creation speed...
64516 NullP sth/s perl 5.018002 darwin-thread-multi-2level (gcc 4.2.1 -Os) 0.000016s

test.pl done



 TIMB/DBI-1.636.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make test -- OK
Running make install
Manifying blib/man1/dbiproxy.1
Manifying blib/man1/dbilogstrip.1
Manifying blib/man1/dbiprof.1
Files found in blib/arch: installing files in blib/lib into architecture dependent library tree
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
ERROR: Can't create '/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level'
Do not have write permissions on '/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level'
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
 at -e line 1.
make: *** [pure_site_install] Error 13
  TIMB/DBI-1.636.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make install  -- NOT OK
----
  You may have to su to root to install the package
  (Or you may want to run something like
    o conf make_install_make_command 'sudo make'
  to raise your permissions.
```

Is there anyway of fixing this error so I can use perl support?

Comment: You need to first learn how to use your chosen operating system before getting into programming. Everything is building correctly, but failing to install because your user does not have permission to write to system locations. Some might suggest you use `sudo`, but **DON'T!**. Instead, build your own `perl` and play with that. The same goes for every other language or library. Do not mess with OS components. See also https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2015/11/apple-recommends-installing-your-own-perl/

Comment: Please don't use `-f`. "Install the module even if it doesn't work" makes no sense!!!

Answer (score 0):

According to the line:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
ERROR: Can't create '/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level'
Do not have write permissions on '/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level'
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

You don't have enough privilegies to install the DBI module. If you really want to install it into your OS you have to use sudo it isn't one of the best practices.

I would recommend you to use [perlbrew](https://perlbrew.pl/), It's quite simple, easy and fast to use and has a lot of nice features and you don't have to worry if you broke up something or not.

Easy to install

> Quicky install:
>
> \curl -L https://install.perlbrew.pl | bash
>
> or
>
> sudo cpan App::perlbrew
>   perlbrew init

You can also install and switch between perl versions:

> To install the latest stable release, and use it permanently:
>
> perlbrew install perl-5.16.0
>
> perlbrew switch perl-5.16.0
>
> To play with the bleeding-edge version, but only in the current shell:
>
> perlbrew install perl-blead
>
> perlbrew use perl-blead

Comment: While you're probably right, you should include an explanation of what _perlbrew_ is good for. Why should it be used, for what, and instead of what? It certainly is not a replacement for adding `sudo` to the `cpan` command.